# Only part of my jQuery mmenu.js menu is displayed

Tags: jquery-mobile, web-applications, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery Mobile in my app with the [mmenu.js plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). When I open my web app on an iPod, a part of my menu doesn't appear. I checked on my iPad, but it looks fine there.

I'm unsure if packaging it as a native app instead of a web app would solve my issue.

Here is the menu portion of my HTML:

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="paginas/buscar.php">Buscar</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/FB_PAGE" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="paginas/creditos.php">Créditos</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('#menu').mmenu({
   position: "left"
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my menu button:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">        
    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
    <h1>Hoy</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not getting displayed? Could it be that it just goes off the screen?

Comment: You might need to show us a screenshot of this.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Just a part doesn't appear.
@hungerpain I can't because I have not enough reputation.

This is just a little bug when is a Web App, when it became in a "native" app this bug is fixed. Thanks to both for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is solved when the web app becomes in a native app.